# Cant get lambda function to do anything

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

What I did:

I created a new python lambda function. Extremely simple and I followed the steps on the website: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html

I created this function per the code provided:

```
import os
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('## ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES')
    print(os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME'])
    print(os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME'])
    print('## EVENT')
    print(event)
```

According to this website I should get the following response:

```
START RequestId: 8f507cfc-xmpl-4697-b07a-ac58fc914c95 Version: $LATEST
## ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
environ({'AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME': '/aws/lambda/my-function', 'AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME': '2020/01/31/[$LATEST]3893xmpl7fac4485b47bb75b671a283c'})
## EVENT
{'key': 'value'}
END RequestId: 8f507cfc-xmpl-4697-b07a-ac58fc914c95
REPORT RequestId: 8f507cfc-xmpl-4697-b07a-ac58fc914c95  Duration: 15.74 ms  Billed Duration: 16 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 56 MB  Init Duration: 130.49 ms
XRAY TraceId: 1-5e34a614-10bdxmplf1fb44f07bc535a1   SegmentId: 07f5xmpl2d1f6f85 Sampled: true
```

However the only output I am getting in the logs is this:

```
// Response:

{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}

// Report

START RequestId: ea55642-341b-47a2-1278-f66e2f16bdb9 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: ea55642-341b-47a2-1278-f66e2f16bdb9
REPORT RequestId: ea55642-341b-47a2-1278-f66e2f16bdb9   Duration: 1.11 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 36 MB  Init Duration: 108.21 ms
```

I changed the runtime to a maximum of 1 min instead of 3 seconds as that was suggested somewhere else but that is not working either.

Am I missing something blatantly obvious here?

Comment: oh @JoachimIsaksson thank you. Yes it does. And now I feel a little stupid. I do however feel that UI could be better for this, perhaps the test button disabled before deploy (if anyone from amazon happens to see this). Thanks again...